# Run-time error '440' - the object does not support this method

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem when running a Macro to send out shipped order emails to customers. It seems to be completely random and follows no pattern. Is there something wrong with the code? I have to go through sent on behalf of, as I need it to show that the email is coming from the main admin account, but VBA highlights the .DESIGNATED line as the problem when it crashes. Here is the code, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub EmailRep()

Do

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Email").Select

End With

Dim sDESIGNATED As String

sDESIGNATED = [C100]
Range("A2:D35").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Item.To = sDESIGNATED
    .Item.Subject = "Your Order Has Shipped!"
    .Item.SentOnBehalfOfName = "me@me.com"
    .Item.Send
End With

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True

    Sheets("Orders").Select
        Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sent").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A2").Select

End With

Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: `.SentOnBehalfOfName` is a property of the Outlook `Mailitem`. I'm not sure you can do this using `MailEnvelope`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! [Why avoid Select](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) and why avoid [implicit references](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) and the [the-macro-recorder-curse/](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/the-macro-recorder-curse/)